# using scanner, how can I get one a cell name contains digit and litter like "A3, B2, C1"

Tags: java, validation, java.util.scanner

how to get two characters input based on a grid naming
i.e "A3, B2, C1" in other words should the input be only two characters and one of them be digit and the other be litter
is there a better way to do that without using these ifs and elses?

note: that it doesn't matter if the input was the number first, it will always pass the litter then numbers

//turning the columns and rows to string here just for the Character's searching issues

```
private static boolean cellsChooser() {
    boolean flag = true;
    boolean getAnotherCell=false;
    char row = '-';
    int columns = -1;
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Enter the cell you want to check");
    while (flag) {
        String stringCell = s.nextLine();
        //there five cases of the input
        // 1 if the user's input is more than 2 characters
        if (stringCell.trim().length() == 2) {
            // 2 if char -> int
            if (Character.isLetter(stringCell.charAt(0))) {
                row = stringCell.toUpperCase().charAt(0);
                if (Character.isDigit(stringCell.charAt(1))) {
                    columns = Integer.parseInt(stringCell.charAt(1) + "");
                    flag = false;
                    // 3 if char -> char
                    } else {
                    System.out.println("Sorry!\njust two characters one of 
                    them digit and the other alphabetic character  ");
                    continue;
                }
                // 4 if int -> char
            } else if (Character.isDigit(stringCell.charAt(0))) {
                columns = columns = Integer.parseInt(stringCell.charAt(0) +"");
                if (Character.isLetter(stringCell.charAt(1))) {
                    row = stringCell.toUpperCase().charAt(1);
                    flag = false;
                // 5 if int -> int
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Sorry!\njust two characters one of 
                    them digit and the other alphabetic character  ");
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: What behavior do you intend for your program?  Do you want the user to input one cell code at a time, or can they also enter CSV values, as the question seems to possibly imply?

Comment: Please include a sample input and expected output.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yeah I want the user the enter one cell at a time, the program will check the cell if it's mine the game will end else it will return how many mines around it then ask the user for another turn

Comment: @NicholasK  all these conditions were made just to be sure that the last value be like "A3, C3" even it's okay if it was "3A" because the function takes each character  (the digit and the litter)apart, but it will ask the user for input again if he passed something like" 33 or BB"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following code :

```
while (true) {
    System.out.println("Enter the cell you want to check");
    String stringCell = nameScanner.nextLine();

    if (stringCell != null && stringCell.trim().length() == 2) {
        if (Character.isLetter(stringCell.charAt(0)) && Character.isDigit(stringCell.charAt(1)))
                break;
    }

    System.err.println("Wrong input");
}
```

Here the loop is broken only if the `stringCell` is of length 2 and if the first character is a letter and if the second character is a digit. This reduces the bulk of your code.

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks, man, it enlightened me about keeping the two ifs (isLetter and isDigit ) in one line, hope you the best tonight against Chelsea :)